# Using Spotify Web Player behind proxy

Tags: spotify, proxy

Spotify Web Player https://play.spotify.com does not work behind my company proxy. Is there a way to use Spotify Web Player when behind a company proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this URL instead (adds `?http=1`):

https://play.spotify.com/?http=1